# Unable to download new packages in R on Mac

Tags: r, macos, ggplot2, package

Since updating R, I cannot seem to download any new packages without running into some errors. Most recently, I am unable to even load the ggplot2 package. Here are the errors I receive:

```
library(ggplot2)

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in rbind(info, getNamespaceInfo(env, "S3methods")):
number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 2) 
    
In addition: Warning messages:

1: In normalizePath(dirname(f)) : path[1]="NA": No such file or directory
2: package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.6.2
```

Can someone tell me what this means/how to fix it?

Comment: Did you recently upgrade to R 4.0.? If yes then you need to reinstall *all* packages before you can use them.

Comment: This notification was after I reinstalled ggplot2

Comment: Well it does write "package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.6.2 " so the one you are trying to load clearly wasn't installed under R 4.0. Did the installation pass without problems? Do you have packages installed both locally as the user and globally?

Comment: So, apparently I just needed to download the app Xcode on Mac, and then re-install ggplot2. I'm not sure why it worked...but it did.